# wifi issue with ubuntu 13.10 and lenovo ideapad s405

Tags: wireless, networking, 13.10

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my laptop lenovo ideapad s405. It's showing all wifi connection.and also connecting to wifi. But it doesn't doing data transfer. Pages are not loading in browser. I have check internet connection its working fine with ethernet connect but not with wifi. Network adpter:Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless network adapter. Please help.

Comment: I had this problem before with my Lenovo Thinkpad X131e. Ultimately, I ended up buying another [adapter](http://pandawireless.com/) for Ubuntu. Luckily, I was able to get a pretty good one for about $10.

Comment: But WiFi was working fine with preinstalled windows. So why do i buy new adapter when its working.

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal command: lspci -nn | grep 0280

Comment: Its Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless network adapter.

Comment: @Rahul That same driver is what caused me trouble. The device worked on Windows, but there were no good Linux drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue on one Xubuntu 13.10 box.

this was my solution and it worked (do this when connected with Ethernet of course)

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source

sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree

sudo modprobe b43
```

reboot and wireless should be working now.

Comment: No its not working for me..:(